# Mysql import from mysqldump in one single command?

Tags: mysql

I need to move a table each day from olddb to new db. I wonder if it is posisble to run this two commands in only one? without creating the .sql file

```
mysqldump -u user olddb table_name > moving.sql
mysql -u user newdb < moving.sql
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Piping mysqldump to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509008/piping-mysqldump-to-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql -u user -p -e 'insert into newdb.table_name select * from olddb.table_name'
```

**UPD**

to use consition:

```
mysql -u user -p -e 'insert into newdb.table_name select * from olddb.table_name where olddb.table_name.mydate > ...'
```

Comment: Mmmm but i only want to import new records, currently the mysqldump is erasing all the table, is posisble to insert only new records?

Comment: I think this is what im looking for: 

INSERT INTO olddb.table_name SELECT * FROM newdb.table_name WHERE newdb.table_name.id > (SELECT id FROM olddb.table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

Comment: `INSERT INTO olddb.table_name SELECT * FROM newdb.table_name WHERE newdb.table_name.id > (SELECT max(olddb.table_name.id) FROM olddb.table_name) ` is better